# Adding document to document manager from a another User Control

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

I have created `3 User Controls` which are called `mainUC`, `collectionUC` and `editUC`.

I've added a `documentManager` in `mainUC` and placed it on the main form.

In my `mainUC`, I've added `collectionUC` as a document.

In my `collectionUC`, there is a button to open `editUC`.

How can I add `editUC` as a new tab when I click a button in `collectionUC` since `documentManager` is in `mainUC`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea is to create an interface of `mainUC` where you expose a method that adds a document to the `documentManager`:

```
public interface IMainUC
{
    void AddDocument();
}

public class MainUC : XtraUserControl, IMainUC
{
    ...

    public void AddDocument()
    {
        EditUC editUC = new EditUC(...);
        ...
        this.documentManager.View.Add(editUC);
    }

    ...
}
```

In your `collectionUC` you pass that interface to the constructor and make it a member variable of your usercontrol.

```
public class CollectionUC : XtraUserControl
{
    private readonly IMainUC m_mainUC;
    public CollectionUC(IMainUC mainUC)
    {
        m_mainUC = mainUC;
    }

    public void MyButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        m_mainUC.AddDocument();
    }
}
```

Of course you could also pass an instance of your `editUC` to the interface method of `mainUC`. 
Hope this helps!

Comment: in such unfortunate case where `CollectionUC` doesn't have object of `MainUC`, he can use `FindForm` method. In `CollectionUC` class' `MyButtonClick` method, he can do : `((MainUC)this.FindForm()).AddDocument()`